# Ember.js: Avoid current route re-enter (and re-render) on url dynamic segment update

Tags: ember.js

Is it possible to update a dynamic parameter in the URL for the **current route** without recreating the route's view?

Specifically, say I have a route that handles `post/:post_id`.  The view for this route shows the post with the given `id` but (in an infinite-scroll style) also allows the user to smoothly scroll down to subsequent posts.  I'd like to update the url to reflect the post they are currently viewing.  If I call `reaplceWith('post', newlyFocusedPost)` the `renderTemplate` hook fires, my original view is destroyed, a new view rendered, and the smoothness is lost.

I'd love the equivalent of Backbone.js's:

```
router.navigate('posts/123', {navigate:false, replace:true});
```

Another solution would be if rendering the same template into the same outlet reused the existing view and just updated its bindings.

*(My current solution is to use a subroute, `postAtId`, that handles the dynamic id with no view plus a call to `controllerFor('post').set('content', newPost)`)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-rendering when only the context has changed is arguably a bug. There is a [pull request](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/2563) that fixes this.

But it's also possible to work around this behavior in your own route by overriding `renderTemplate` so that it only renders immediately after entering the route for the first time. For example:

```
App.MyRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  activate: function() {
    this.needsToRender = true;
  },
  renderTemplate: function() {
    if (this.needsToRender){
      this.needsToRender = false;
      render();
    }
  }
});
```